# Copy cell selection from Excel into JSF 2 component

Tags: excel, jsf-2, components, copy-paste

I need to copy the data of multiple excel cells into a JSF2 component.
It does not matter whether it's a primefaces, openfaces or richfaces component.
Primefaces has a nice component called sheet, but I don't think it provides the feature to copy data from excel to it.

Can anybody tell me, if there is a way? I do not want to use a file upload.

Comment: how about paste it into `p:editor` ? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/editor.jsf

Comment: That unfortunatelly does not satisfy the requirements, I need the sheet structure (cols, rows).

Comment: JSF2 does not provide such a component. I took a look on other techniques and found this GWT component: http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#excel_to_grid_category_new